# How to calculate mean values grouped on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the following dataframe:

```
StationID  HoursAhead    BiasTemp  
SS0279           0          10
SS0279           1          20
KEOPS            0          0
KEOPS            1          5
BB               0          5
BB               1          5
```

I'd like to get something like:

```
StationID  BiasTemp  
SS0279     15
KEOPS      2.5
BB         5
```

I know I can script something like this to get the desired result:

```
def transform_DF(old_df,col):
    list_stations = list(set(old_df['StationID'].values.tolist()))
    header = list(old_df.columns.values)
    header.remove(col)
    header_new = header
    new_df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = header_new)
    for i,station in enumerate(list_stations):
        general_results = old_df[(old_df['StationID'] == station)].describe()
        new_row = []
        for column in header_new:
            if column in ['StationID']: 
                new_row.append(station)
                continue
            new_row.append(general_results[column]['mean'])
        new_df.loc[i] = new_row
    return new_df
```

But I wonder if there is something more straightforward in pandas.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You could `groupby` on `StationID` and then take `mean()` on `BiasTemp`. To output `Dataframe`, use `as_index=False`

```
In [4]: df.groupby('StationID', as_index=False)['BiasTemp'].mean()
Out[4]:
  StationID  BiasTemp
0        BB       5.0
1     KEOPS       2.5
2    SS0279      15.0
```

Without `as_index=False`, it returns a `Series` instead

```
In [5]: df.groupby('StationID')['BiasTemp'].mean()
Out[5]:
StationID
BB            5.0
KEOPS         2.5
SS0279       15.0
Name: BiasTemp, dtype: float64
```

Read more about `groupby` in this pydata [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Comment: how different would this be, from doing something like `.transform(numpy.mean)` or  `.apply(numpy.mean)`?

Answer (score 16):

This is what [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html#pandas.Series.groupby) is for:

```
In [117]:
df.groupby('StationID')['BiasTemp'].mean()

Out[117]:
StationID
BB         5.0
KEOPS      2.5
SS0279    15.0
Name: BiasTemp, dtype: float64
```

Here we groupby the 'StationID' column, we then access the 'BiasTemp' column and call `mean` on it

There is a section in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) on this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

can be done as follows:

```
df.groupby('StationID').mean()
```