# Pandas: calculate mean by specific value in column with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, mean

I have a dataset which has consecutive rows with a 'marker' (numbers 0,1,2,....) which indicates that all of these rows belong to the same 'picture'(e.g. marker = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,....]). Now I want my programme to give me the mean of each 'picture', e.g all with number = 0 belong to picture 0 and calculate the mean of the whole data frame within that marker. So far I tried this:

```
###Read data in: 
df = pd.read_csv(path_i, sep = ",")

#### Calculate means per picture: 

number = 0

for i in df:
      picture = df.marker[number]
      means = df.mean(picture)
      number = number + 1
```

my code gives me output: however it is the same for every line: I think since im expecting about 96 pictures, it gives me the mean of the whole data frame.

```
Unnamed: 0       18547.000000
index            18548.000000
pos_time        341778.900067
pos_x              -95.375306
pos_y              -64.948367
pup_time        341778.900067
pup_diameter         3.116594
marker              48.336649
which_AOI            1.637822
fixation            17.559536
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate mean values grouped on another column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482071/how-to-calculate-mean-values-grouped-on-another-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('marker').mean()
```

And if need `marker` as column in output:

```
df1 = df.groupby('marker', as_index=False).mean()
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('marker').mean().reset_index()
```